# Is it acceptable to create *this.form* twice in a component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I had following *ngOnInit()* and *init()*.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe(_ => this.service.getThing(_.id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        this.init();
      })
    );
}

private init() {
  ...
  this.form = new FormGroup({ ... });
}
```

It threw an exception that *this.form* needs to exists to bind to the *[formGroup]* attribute. So I created an empty, field-less instance of *FormGroup* like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({ });
  this.route.params
    .subscribe( ... );
}
```

However, it then started to complain that the fields referred to by *formControlName* in the template aren't found (which undeniably is true, too). So I ended up invoking *init()* method twice. Once immediately after I've created a dummy instance of *Thing* assigning it to *this.data*. Then again after the subsciption has ticked in with its value. It seems a bit clunky and hacky so I wonder if there's a better way to resolve it.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe(_ => this.service.getThing(_.id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        this.init();
      })
    );

  this.data = new Thing();
  this.init();
}
```

Is there a best practice for poking the form group to let it know that the data used in the binding to reactive fields has changed (so I can skip the second call to *this.init()*)? Or is there a best practice to delaying the reactivity to the fields before data subscribed to has been delivered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the best solution here is to make the form a child component. Then handle the data loading in the parent component. This makes it so you can easily wait until the form data loads before generating the form. This looks something like this:

Here is the container component template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="formData$ | async as formData; else loading">
  <dynamic-form [formData]="formData"></dynamic-form>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading>
  <div>Loading ...</div>
</ng-template>
```

and script:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Thing, ThingService } from './thing.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'form-container',
  templateUrl: './formContainer.component.html'
})
export class FormContainerComponent {
  public formData$ = this.route.params.pipe(
    switchMap(_ => this.service.getThing(_.id)),
    map((thing: Thing) => thing.form)
  );

  constructor(
    private readonly route: RouteSnapshot,
    private readonly service: ThingService
  ) {}
}
```

Then your form component would look something like this:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-form',
  templateUrl: './dynamicForm.component.html'
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() formData: any;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    // here we can now use the formData synchronously.
    this.form = new FormGroup({ ... });
  }
}
```

This also give you a good separation; as you can see I added a simple loading pattern. You can also put error patterns in the container as well. Another advantage to doing this way is the built in memory release from the `async` pipe.

Another solution is to load the data in a resolver so it is there as soon as you get to the route.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a short sample showing what you mean? No complete working code as it might get large. Just a few lines pointing out the direction.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response - had to leave for dinner. This is a pattern I use often in things that load after the page.

Comment: I tried to check the example for a few days but a few things confuse me. I don't see where the *id* from the parameters from route is passed to the service call. I also can't find the spot where we actually subscribe to the whole observable that you're piping together.

Comment: I just updated the passing of the id in the same way you did (`_ => this.getThing(_.id)` - the subscribe happens in the template by `async` and for that reason, it is unsubscribed when the template is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your `FormGroup` before any lifecycle hooks like `ngOnInit`.

```
constructor() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    a: new FormControl(''),
    b: new FormControl(''),
    ...
  })
}
```

Now the ui has all necessary form elements and won't crash.

To get your asynchronous data into the form you can now call the `reset` or `setValue` method of the `FormGroup`, like:

```
constructor() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    a: new FormControl(''),
    b: new FormControl(''),
   ...
  })

  this.route.params
    .subscribe(_ => this.service.getThing(_.id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        this.form.reset(data);
      })
    );
}
```